# Language of app web

Tags: sharepoint-addin, access, language

I'm working on an Access SharePoint app but I think this also applies to SharePoint hosted apps. When I create a new app, the app runs in an app web which is automatically created. The language of this app web is **English (or En-us 1033)**. I try to get data from a list in another web which is **Dutch (or Nl-nl 1043)** my app can't read items from the list because the apps need to be the same language. So my question is:

what is responsible for the automatically created app web's language and how do I change the standard/default language of my app web (I want it to be Dutch).

Comment: Of course I want it to be Dutch when it is created and not change it afterwards.

Comment: Your app manifest has a tab for supported locales.  Perhaps adding your language there would solve your issue.  I'm not 100%, as I've only had to develop for English.

Comment: I haven't been able to find any language settings in Access. When I save my app as a package and check the app manifest, it says nl-NL so that's not the way to go.

Comment: My bad, just realized you are using Access.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I figured it out. The app web is created in the OS (client) language when created from Access. It is created in the language of the host web when you add it through site contents-> add an app -> Access App. After you're added the access app you can edit it with Access.